# Backing up to an existing Time Machine sparsebundle

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, osx-server

I have been using OS X Mavericks Server Time Machine Backup service to backup my laptops. I recently had to move my backup sparsebundles to a new drive. I've reconfigured Time Machine server to point to that new drive and I see my backups in Time Machine server console.

However, when I point my laptop to the Time Machine server, my existing sparsebundle "MightyMac" does get used. Instead, my laptop starts a brand new backup as "MightyMac1".

How can I force my laptop to use "MightyMac" and preserve the historical backups and prevent a new backup file from being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I needed to make the user whose account is being used to authenticate to the Time Machine mount point from the remote laptop the owner of the `MightyMac.sparsebundle` file. I discovered this by comparing the permissions on the new sparsebundle it created with the old one I wanted to backup to and found the new one was owned by the remote user and the old one was not.

After I made the remote user owner of the old sparsebundle Time Machine backed-up to the old sparsebundle file.